# Android, spinner items not showing

Tags: java, android, string, spinner, items

This is my code and I can not get the items add inside Spinner.
I don't know what's going wrong, and unable to find any other way!

Java:

```
 spinner = (Spinner)getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner);

 String[] datos = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);

 ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, datos);
adaptador.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 spinner.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

XML:

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_margin="26dp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"/>
```

strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="items">
    <item >Item 1</item>
    <item >Item 2</item>
    <item >Item 3</item>
    <item >Item 4</item>
</string-array>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: what is your question? items not showing in spinner?

Comment: Yes, the items not showing in sppiner

Comment: @user3139428 there is no fault in your code it should work... could you please add more java code to check further?

Comment: I checked your code in my project. Its working fine.

Comment: in my case it was because of the theme of the activity, try changing that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your spinner text color is white: change it to other color.

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_margin="26dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"/>  //change this
```

also you can directly access the array resource in your layout. Like:

```
android:entries="@array/items" //add this in your spinner layout
```

**EDIT**

you can try using a custom layout for your spinner item:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:background="#000000"  //dark background
    android:text="Test"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"  //white text
    android:padding="5dp"
    />
```

use the layout using:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
        R.layout.spinner_item, datos);
```

here `R.layout.spinner_item` is the spinner custom layout

Comment: Ok, thank you very much I noticed the problem, the spinner does not recognize the white color, and I have the background in dark gray.
How can I do to put the text in white?

Answer (score 2):

In my case just added some padding in the XML file.

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinnerMuestreo"
      android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textViewNumMuestreo"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="8dp" <!--Try adding this line. -->
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This XML Only**

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_margin="26dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:entries="@array/items"/>
```

**Remove Below From Acticity**

```
String[] datos = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);

 ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, datos);adaptador.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

 spinner.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<resources>
<string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
    <item>Jupiter</item>
    <item>Saturn</item>
    <item>Uranus</item>
    <item>Neptune</item>
</string-array>
```

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
  // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner

 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

on selected item

```
 public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {
...

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}
 }
```

before that ..

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```