# Text not showing in Array adapter Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-arrayadapter

I am working on Array adapter dialog box where I need to show two phone numbers. The problem is that my numbers are not displaying there, only empty space is showing, but when I am click on any of the space it is showing me that numbers are there but it is not showing.

My code is given below:

```
public void showDialog(List<String> array) {

  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

  final ArrayAdapter<String> arraylist=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, array);

  builder.setSingleChoiceItems(arraylist, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
           phoneCall(arraylist.getItem(item));
           dialog.dismiss();
          }

        });
 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
 alert.setTitle("تماس");
 alert.show();

}
```

[image]

Comment: check `array` size and print please

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thanks for your reply. My Arraysize is 2 and numbers are: 1234, 5678.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202985/android-spinner-items-not-showing

Comment: You should use custom layout and set textcolor just

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya this solution not always work, there is some issue on high API'S.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem, guidance given to me by @IntelliJ Amiya. I am doing following mechanism to do it.

Method where i am calling this Dialog box:

```
 ListAdapter adapter  = new PhoneDialogAdapter(Kasab_o_karahi_activity_detail.this, array);

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        //AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.CustomAlertDialogTheme));

        builder.setTitle("تماس").setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                        String number = (adapter.getItem(item)+"");
                        phoneCall(number);
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).show();
```

Custom Adapter Class:

```
public class PhoneDialogAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private List<Integer> images;

        public PhoneDialogAdapter(Context context, List<String> items) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
            this.images = images;
        }

        public PhoneDialogAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
//            textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(images.get(position), 0, 0, 0);
            textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding((int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 12, getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
            return view;
        }

    }
```